# Export Data via Elasticdump for an Elasticsearch index not working (or alternative ways)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elasticsearch docker container from which I want to export data in a human readable file format for further analysis. For that I have tried to use elasticdump (other tolls that do the the same are also recommend to know if you can tell me them). When I try to export the mapping information it works but not not when I try the data.

My command just switching the type from mapping to data

```
elasticdump --input=http://localhost:9200/sessions2-110125 --output=/usr/share/elasticsearch/dump/sessions2-110125.json --type=mapping
```

For mapping I get:

```
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:25:04 GMT | starting dump 
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:25:04 GMT | got 1 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 0)
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:25:04 GMT | sent 1 objects to destination file, wrote 1
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:25:04 GMT | got 0 objects from source elasticsearch (offset: 1)
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:25:04 GMT | Total Writes: 1
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:25:04 GMT | dump complete
```

For data I get:

```
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:24:42 GMT | starting dump
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:24:42 GMT | Error Emitted => {"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:24:42 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Tue, 16 Nov 2021 10:24:42 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: {"error":"Content-Type header [] is not supported","status":406}
```

I found out that I have to specify the header with the argument

```
--headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}'
```

but despite that it doesn't change the error message.

Comment: I think the single and double quotes characters you're using (`”` and `’`) are not the right ones. Try this instead: `--headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}'`

Comment: Thanks for the info it shouldn't look like that don’t know why it did. And found my problem, yum has an older version off npm in its database and through that I got an older version of elasticdump which didn’t work as it should.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!